# Paper border on plotly R graph

Tags: r, plotly

Not sure if R's plot_ly function has this capability (i havent been able to find it), but figured I'd ask). Plot_ly does have a paper_bgcolor parameter that changes the color of the paper that the plot is on, as such:

```
mydf = data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)

plot_ly(mydf) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~x, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
            marker = list(size = 24)) %>%
  layout(paper_bgcolor = 'red')
```

I am not interested in changing the paper color, but rather the paper border. That is, I'd like a red box around the outer edge of the paper. Does anybody know a simple way to do this?

EDIT — I think I may have to use the grid package for this / it could be done with grid, but I'm curious first if it's possible without incorporating another package.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to modify the CSS file used by Plotly.

- Find the location of your directory storing the plotly-min.js and the CSS file

  ```
  p <- plot_ly()
  p$dependencies[[4]]$src$file
  ```
- Output:

  > [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTFbO.png)
  >   "/that/is/my/directory/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/plotly/htmlwidgets/lib/plotlyjs"
- Go to this directory and copy `plotly-htmlwidgets.css` to a new file, e.g. `plotly-htmlwidgets_red.css`
- Add the following lines to the new file

  ```
  div.svg-container {
    outline:5px solid red;
  }
  ```
- Tell plotly to use your new CSS file

  ```
  p <- plot_ly()
  p$dependencies[[4]]$stylesheet <- "plotly-htmlwidgets_red.css"
  ```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the creative suggestion. I'm fairly confident that plotly's function itself doesn't have a parameter for what I want, I've looked in the docs a bit for it. I think there's probably a better approach here if I use the grid package, but i agree this does get the job done.